# Angular6: Open dialog based on selected value in dropdown

Tags: angular, select, dialog, dropdown

I have a `p-dropdown` with a list containing multiple options to select `[options]="newUnitSelectItems"`. The goal is: if the user selects "other" from that list of options, a new dialog should open. If the user selects any other value from the list, a simple `console.log` should be performed. How do I achieve this?

```
new.component.html
      <p-dropdown name="newUnit" id="newUnit" [options]="newUnitSelectItems"
                  [(ngModel)]="Id"
                  (onChange)="performConsoleLog(Id, 'calc')"
                  ></p-dropdown>


new.component.ts
  performConsoleLog(unit: string, parameter: string) {
    if (parameter === 'calc') {
     console.log("No dialog open, unit: " + unit);
    }
  }

  newUnitSelectItems() {
    let selectItems: SelectItem[] = [
      {label: "%", value:"%"},
      {label: "g", value:"g"},
      {label: "other", value:"other"}
    ];
    return selectItems;
  }
```

I suppose the `(onChange)` is wrong here, because `performConsoleLog()` is called on every click. Is there a way to check which value is selected from `[options]="newUnitSelectItems"` in the html?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the `command` in options of `p-dropdown`.

```
 newUnitSelectItems() {
    let selectItems: SelectItem[] = [
      {label: "%", value:"%"},
      {label: "g", value:"g"},
      {label: "other", value:"other", command :()=> this.openModal()} //<--command is here
    ];

   openModal(){
     console.log("Opening modal ");
   }
```

Remove `onChange` from select box.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$event` of `change` event to get the value selected :

```
<p-dropdown name="newUnit" id="newUnit" [options]="newUnitSelectItems"
                  [(ngModel)]="Id"
                  (onChange)="performConsoleLog($event)"
                  ></p-dropdown>
```

in your TS :

```
performConsoleLog($event) {
    if ($event.value.label === 'other') {
     // open your dialog.
    }
}
```

Regards,